# Copy Bevel modifier to selected gives undesired result

Tags: bevel, object-mode

I tried to copy the bevel modifier to the selected wheels as you can see in the first picture, but when I do this something strange happens - which you can see in the second picture.

When I don't try to copy the modifier but just add modifier to the wheels itself, nothing happens - no bevel at all.

What is going wrong?

Here is the file:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added the file!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have overlapping faces and it seems to mess up with the *Geometry > Miter Outer > Arc* setting. Merge by distance to fix it. I don't know what *Arc* is for but it looks like once you've merged the vertices it works.

Comment: Great that worked!